# X / Y axis + Extruder not working on respective ports

Tags: troubleshooting, creality-ender-3

On an Ender 3, the X, Y and extruder are not moving when using the prepare menu to move them. If I change the motherboard port for Y to the Z port, the Y moves fine, same goes for the other axis that are not working in their respective ports - so it's not the motor or the cable. What else could be wrong? I find it unlikely that 2/3 axis and extruder are all stopped working at the same time.

I have tried "auto home" but before anything moves it says "Homing failed PRINTER HALTED Please reset". The y axis seems to have a light humming noise to it, but no movement at all.

Seems like all of the stop switches are being ignored. When I "Home Z" with any stop switch plugged into the Z-stop, it just continues along even when i trigger the stop manually. This eventually means it hits the end of the axis and just keeps hitting the end with a nasty vibrating sound.

It was working for about 6 months before all this and my old power supply popped, replaced the power supply and all this started.

I have tried a pre-built marlin 1.1.9 firmware, then tried a self-built marlin 1.1.9 firmware that I followed a guide to do specifically for the Ender 3 and then flashed TH3D U1.R2.15 unified firmware using their instructions and still the problem persists through all firmwares

Comment: Hi and welcome to 3DP.SE! You basically established that X and Y only work on the Z header. Have you checked the endstops (e.g. inverted logic or incorrectly wired; try pressing an endstop switch when moving the axis, also note to home the printer first)? Also note that the extruder will only move when it is above a certain temperature, usually over 170 ºC. Please update your question by [edit] to include additional information that is asked through the comments.

Comment: also, how long did you have the printer running beforehand?

Comment: updated the question with the answers to your questions, thanks!

Comment: It sounds to me like the firmware may have become corrupt when the power supply popped... It's the only thing I can think of that would cause this bizarre behaviour! If you have an Arduino there are plenty of tutorials that explain how to reflash the firmware.

Comment: updated question with more info regarding firmwares, thanks !

Comment: Maybe the question should be: "Is it possible that blowing my printers power supply wrecks up my printer?"

Comment: @0scar you might be right. i loaded the stock (unsafe) firmware on the creality3d repo just to make sure it wasnt the firmware and still the same issue. goes to start testing capacitors / resistors and see if i can find something there.